# printable responsive layout

Tags: css, print, media-queries

I'm quite a newbie in web design.
I'm starting off with a W3 template. Please see this one as illustration: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_food_blog.htm .
I'm trying to implement media query to be able to print as the gridded image layout that is shown. However, this layout seems to force the images to become full page upon printing. I've consulted many explanations of how to implement @media print, however they do not seem to address what I need.

If someone could provide some insight that would be great.

Edit: I guess my question was not focused enough. So in edit.
I've added a print.css and included:
@media print { body { width: 70%;}}

This pulls the image grid in to a vertical organization of the images instead of preserving the grid layout. The image width is 70% of the max width.

MrWhite has already giving me the advice that setting print settings at 70% would print the layout, but how can I set that as default in css?

Thank you.

Comment: I commend you for considering the "print" stylesheet. Many sites do neglect this area these days (even Amazon gets it "wrong" with it's return postage labels). When printing I always have to vary the scaling to get it "right". And if you reduce the scaling to 70 - 90% for the example you link to, it prints "OK" (it switches from "mobile" - full page images to "desktop" 4 x 2 grid), although it doesn't seem to do anything specific for "print". A "print" stylesheet should also "hide" unnecessary navigation elements and be mindful that backgrounds are not printed by default etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I see what you mean! Sizing the print to 70% is basically what I would be happy with. So I try to do this in the css. I made a separate print.css and in the html inserted "/print.css" media="print">" and the page seems to be responding. However, it loses the grid layout, which is similar to the problem I was having before. I have " @media print { body {
    width: 70%;}} " in the print.css, is there another way that's more correct? I can't seem to find the proper documentation for this...this pulls the images into vertical single column at 70% width of page ...=/

Comment: For best results in my experience: any desired styling that's inside a media query in your regular CSS should be copied into the print stylesheet as well. I've seen odd things where the way the print view laid out varied depending on how large the browser window was. Print styling is difficult and takes some trial and error and a lot of print preview - good luck!